# ¿Cómo correr dos archivos de Python a la vez?

Tags: python

Tengo dos programas simples los cuales son:

```
import random
import time

while(True):
    ran1=random.randint(30,40)
    print(ran1)
    time.sleep(1.0)
```

y

```
import random
import time

while(True):
    ran2=random.randint(50,60)
    print(ran2)
    time.sleep(1.0)
```

Quiero que ambos funcionen a la vez pero desde diferentes archivos.py para otro uso donde quiero correr dos programas al mismo tiempo.

Sin embargom al activar un codigo y luego el otro, el primero se detiene automáticamente.

Adjunto imagen de lo que estoy usando para ello.
[image: introducir la descripción de la imagen aquí]

Quisiera saber de que forma puedo lograr mi objetivo de correr dos archivos.py al mismo tiempo.

Comment: Debe ser por el editor que estás utilizando, si ejecutas los programas desde dos terminales distintas te debería dejar sin ningún problema.

Comment: Tienes razon compañero, no habia pensado en ello, gracias por tu respuesta. Porfavor ponlo como respuesta para poder aceptarlo.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Tu editor puede estar limitando el comportamiento que esperas. Lo que puedes intentar es correr en diferentes terminales cada programa y se va a crear un nuevo proceso por cada uno así que sin ningún problema te va a correr